# A question on Unbounded set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the following is the unbounded set ?

1. $ X = \{ x\mid x = \frac{1}{n},n \in \mathbb{N} \} $
2. $ Y = \{ x\mid x = \frac{1}{2^n},n \in  \mathbb{N} \} $
3. $ Z = \{ x\mid x = 2^n,n \in \mathbb{N} \} $
4. $ W = \{ x\mid x \in \mathbb{N}, x \lt 4532 \} $

After reading the definition from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) , I can only convince myself that it can't be W but am not getting which is correct from the other three ?

Comment: Think about What is the definition for a bounded set and an unbounded?

Comment: finite and infinite ?

Comment: What is finite and infinite?

Comment: Why did you have to go to wikipedia for a definition of bounded? The problem givers didn't provide one? Also, did you look at the **Definition** section in the wiki page you linked?

Comment: Next time you're writing sets in LaTeX, try this: $W = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{N} \; \middle\vert \;  x < 4532\right\rbrace$. To see the source, just right click on the math and click "show source". And I do know that `\middle` doesn't work here, but it's in `amsmath`.

Comment: @Moron: No they haven't given the definition up-to what I have finished till today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** When do you say that a set is bounded.

- *A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is said to be bounded if you can find a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| \leq M$ for all $x \in X$.*

Now consider your cases:

- $X = \{ x | x = \frac{1}{n} ; \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ **NOTE:** $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- Similarly the Second one.
- Now , the third one is unbounded. (Why?). Assume $2^{n} \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and obtain a contradiction.
- Fourth one follows from the definition.

Comment: @Chandru1 I think you're missing an absolute value in your definition of a bounded set, or maybe you're just interested in saying it is bounded above.

Answer (score 7):

A set in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if you can find two numbers, $a$ and $b$ such that all elements of the set are between $a$ and $b$.  If you want to claim a set is unbounded, whatever $a$ and $b$ I give you, you should be able to find at least one element outside the interval $(a,b)$.  Which of your sets satisfies that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the concept :)